# "permission denied" laravel new homestead ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04, homestead

when i run `laravel new <new project>` i got error like this

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/Code/laravel_6c11ebb11f0426f74820afdfb31f24e2.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 139
```

i have run `sudo chmod -R 777 <name folder>` and `sudo chown -R vagrant <name folder>` but still got the same error.

I try to make new folder with `mkdir` and i got `permission denied`. i guessed this about permission problem. but i don't how to solve it

Comment: where you have the permissions problem run: sudo chown -R $USER <folder name>. Then you should be able to run chmod or whatever you want inside that folder.

Comment: i have do that, but still got the problem